# Error in Installing redmine 1.1.2

Tags: ruby, rake, redmine, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8

I have to install redmine 1.1.2 and for that the rails version should be 2 and ruby version should be 1.8.7. And now as we moved to the rails 3 and ruby 1.9 +, I am getting many errors in installing redmine 1.1.2.

And now I am getting an error:-

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
>       cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rake.

when using: `rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p371@red1 && gem uninstall rake -v 10.0.4`